# Adding Html from Code Behind in Asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0, dynamic, code-behind

I want to add HTML structure and control like this from code behind into a panel

```
<div class='Main'>
    <div class='cst'>
        First Name
    </div>
    <div class='csc'>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" CssClass="ronly" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class='cst'>
        First Name
    </div>
    <div class='csc'>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" CssClass="ronly" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>        <div class='cst'>
        First Name
    </div>
    <div class='csc'>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" CssClass="ronly" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class='end'>
    </div>
</div>

  <asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="sxpnl" ID="pnlUserdata">
        </asp:Panel>
```

If i try to add like this

```
 HtmlGenericControl divcontrol = new HtmlGenericControl();
 divcontrol.Attributes["class"] = "sxro sx1co";
 divcontrol.TagName = "div";
 pnlUserSearch.Controls.Add(divcontrol);
 Label question = new Label();
 questionDescription.Text = "text";
 pnlUserSearch.Controls.Add(question);
```

It will add controls one after another, how can i make controls go nested like that as shown above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't add that child control to the panel, add it to the control that **should** be the parent:

```cs
HtmlGenericControl divcontrol = new HtmlGenericControl();
divcontrol.Attributes["class"] = "sxro sx1co";
divcontrol.TagName = "div";
pnlUserSearch.Controls.Add(divcontrol);

Label question = new Label();
question.Text = "text";
divcontrol.Controls.Add(question); // add to the new div, not to the panel
```

Answer (score 39):

For appending HTML to your panel, add a `LiteralControl` control to your panel:

```
string yourHTMLstring = "<div class='Main'>....";
pnlUserdata.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(yourHTMLstring));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Take one local string variable TEMP.
2. Create same html as you want to display on screen and store it in variable TEMP.
3. You can take html creation of control in separate function based on requirement.
4. Place that created html as innerHTML to your panel/div.

That's it...

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="Div1" runat="server">

Div1.InnerText = "Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the div `runat="server"`

```
<div id="d" runat="server"></div>
```

and add the controls inside div like below

```
d.Controls.Add();
```

Comment: i have a panel as runat="server" and i can add controls in that, but the question is how to making nesting like that.