# Create html elements from code behind and display to front-end in ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I need to Read/Display some front-end code/elements from Code Behind.
Scenario: I have a page, in which I have two (2) `<div>`, the top `<div>` and the bottom `<div>`.

I have two buttons inside top `<div>` as given below and the `<div>` at bottom is blank. Below is the code snippet:

`Default.aspx`:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="navbar">
                <asp:Button ID="btnHome" runat="server" Text="Home"
                    OnClick="btnHome_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnProducts" runat="server" Text="Products"
                    OnClick="btnProducts_Click" />
            </div>
            <div id="contentArea">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click the home button, some `HTML` elements should become part of the `Default.aspx` page inside a `<div>` given below:

```html
<div id=contentArea">
</div>
```

The above code should look like the code below:

```html
<div id="contentArea">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>Home Elements here</p>
</div>
```

When I click `Product` button, so that the code look like:

```html
<div id="contentArea">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <p>Products Elements here</p>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkMicrosoft" runat="server" Text="Go to Microsoft"
        NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com"></asp:HyperLink>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkGoogle" runat="server" Text="Go to Google"
        NavigateUrl="http://www.google.com"></asp:HyperLink>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to manipulate contentArea, you should make it runat="server"

Comment: Thanks for such a fully working advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ***Panel*** to display html contents which renders as div tag.

*For example,*

### ASPX

```
<div id="navbar">
    <asp:Button ID="btnHome" runat="server" Text="Home" OnClick="btnHome_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnProducts" runat="server" Text="Products" 
        OnClick="btnProducts_Click" />
</div>
<asp:Panel ID="contentArea" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
```

### Code Behind

```
protected void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var h1 = new HtmlGenericControl("h1") {InnerText = "Home"};
    contentArea.Controls.Add(h1);

    var p = new HtmlGenericControl("p") {InnerText = "Home Elements here"};
    contentArea.Controls.Add(p);
}

protected void btnProducts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var h1 = new HtmlGenericControl("h1") {InnerText = "Products"};
    contentArea.Controls.Add(h1);

    var p = new HtmlGenericControl("p") {InnerText = "Products Elements here"};
    contentArea.Controls.Add(p);

    var lnkMicrosoft = new HyperLink
    {
        Text = "Go to Microsoft",
        NavigateUrl = "http://www.microsoft.com"
    };
    contentArea.Controls.Add(lnkMicrosoft);

    var lnkGoogle = new HyperLink
    {
        Text = "Go to Google",
        NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com"
    };
    contentArea.Controls.Add(lnkGoogle);
}
```

Comment: Bundle of Thanks Dear, Like it and Love it, its working and fulfill my requirements. God Bless you ever

Comment: This answer suited my needs a little better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20855024/1415929